lua require works in CMD but not in VSCode debugger
I'm trying to debug a lua program using VSCode with Lua Debug.
This is the program
require 'luaxml'
print('Hello')

When I run it from the CMD it works fine.
But when I run it from VSCode it complains the library cannot be found
C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\lua.exe: C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua/luaxml.lua:1: module 'LuaXML_lib' not found:
        no field package.preload['LuaXML_lib']
        no file './LuaXML_lib.lua'
        no file 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua/LuaXML_lib.lua'
        no file 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua/LuaXML_lib/init.lua'
        no file 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/LuaXML_lib.lua'
        no file 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/LuaXML_lib/init.lua'
        no file 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua/LuaXML_lib.luac'
        no file 'C:\Users\Me\Documents/LuaXML_lib.lua'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1/LuaXML_lib.lua'
        no file 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\LuaXML_lib.lua'
        no file 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\LuaXML_lib.dll'
        no file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1/LuaXML_lib.dll'
        no file 'C:\Users\Me\Documents\LuaXML_lib.dll'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        C:/Program Files (x86)/Lua/5.1/lua/luaxml.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ...Documents\test.lua:4: in main chunk
        [C]: ?

This is the content of my launch.json. I have specified the path to the lua that runs when I call which lua from the CMD.
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lua",
            "luaexe": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Lua\\5.1\\lua.exe",
            "request": "launch",
            "luaVersion": "lua51",
            "luaArch": "x86",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\test.lua",
            "cwd": "C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents",
            "arg": ["C:\\Users\\Me\\Documents\\output"]
        }
    ]
}

Why is the debugger version from Lua unable to find the library ? Why isn't it exactly the same executable as the one from the CMD ? (since it is the one I specified in launch.json).

One possible difference could be the working directory, where is the xml lib and from what working dir do you start using cmd?

I performed my test by using the working directory specified in cwd from launch.json. So they are identical.

where is LuaXML_lib on your machine?

LuaXML_lib is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\Lua\5.1\clibs\LuaXML_lib.dll
